# Log4J SMTP digest/aggregate emails?

Tags: java, smtp, log4j, aggregate, digest

I have a JBOSS batch application that sometimes sends hundreds on emails in a minute to the same email address with Log4J errors.  This causes problems with Gmail, because it says we are sending emails too quickly for that gmail account.

So I was wondering if there was a way to basically create a "digest" or "aggregate" email puts all the error logs in 1 email and sends that every 5 minutes.  So that way every 5 minutes we may get a large email, but at least we actually get the email instead of it being delayed for hours and hours by gmail servers rejecting it.

I read [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/logback-user@qos.ch/msg01514.html) that suggested something about using an evaluator to do that, but I couldn't see how that is configured in the Log4J xml configuration file.  It also seemed like it might not be able to "digest" all the logs into 1 email anyway.

Has anyone done this before? Or know if it's possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From (the archived) [SMTPAppender Usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20100201073255/http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=9913) page:

set this property

```
log4j.appender.myMail.evaluatorClass = com.mydomain.example.MyEvaluator
```

Now you have to create the evaluator class and implement the `org.apache.log4j.spi.TriggeringEventEvaluator` interface and place this class in a path where log4j can access it.

```
//Example TriggeringEventEvaluator impl

package com.mydomain.example;

import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.TriggeringEventEvaluator;

public class MyEvaluator implements TriggeringEventEvaluator {

    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LoggingEvent event) { 
        return true; 
    }

}
```

You have to write the evaluator logic within this method.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like it would do the job.  In the end I switched off email's all together because it was getting out of hand.  However, if I'm required to switch it back on, this will definitely help!

Comment: I have been keeping wondering why my email appender is not working. The log4j xsd might be better if they can provide feedback on malformed configuration. Combine Threshold or logger level with SMTPAppender, without throwing exception is really confusing. While the only way to change logging level for SMTPAppender is actually implement and provide TriggeringEventEvaluator.

Answer (score 0):

I created a free useable solution for log4j2 with an **`ExtendedSmtpAppender`**.
(If you still use log4j 1.x, simply replace your `log4j-1.x.jar` with `log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar` - and `log4j-core-2.x.jar` + `log4j-api-2.x.jar` of course.)

You get it from Maven Central as [`de.it-tw:log4j2-extras`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:de.it-tw%20AND%20a:log4j2-extras) (This requires Java 7+ and log4j 2.8+).
If you are restricted to Java 6 (and thus log4j 2.3) then use [`de.it-tw:log4j2-Java6-extras`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:de.it-tw%20AND%20a:log4j2-Java6-extras)

Additionally, see the GitLab project:  https://gitlab.com/thiesw/log4j2-extras  (or  https://gitlab.com/thiesw/log4j2-Java6-extras)

*[OLD text:

If you use log4j2, see answer to other stack overflow issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34072704/5074004*

*Or directly go to my external but publically available solution presented in  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1192

]*